# extracting data from two list using a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to create a shell script that pulls a line from a file and checks another file for an instance of the same. If it finds an entry then it adds it to another file and loops through the first list until the it has gone through the whole file. The data in the first file looks like this -

```
email@address.com;
email2@address.com;
and so on
```

The other file in which I am looking for a match and placing the match in the blank file looks like this -

```
12334    email@address.com;
32213    email2@address.com;
```

I want it to retain the numbers as well as the matching data. I have an idea of how this should work but need to know how to implement it.

#### My Idea

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "enter first file name:" file1
read -p "enter second file name:" file2
FILE_DATA=( $( /bin/cat $file1))
FILE_DATA1=( $( /bin/cat $file2))
for I in $((${#FILE_DATA[@]}))
     do 
     echo $FILE_DATA[$i] | grep $FILE_DATA1[$i] >> output.txt
     done
```

I want the output to look like this but only for addresses that match -

```
12334 email@address.com;
32213 email2@address.com;
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read line by the file1.txt file and assign the line to var ADDR. grep file2.txt with the content of var ADDR and append the output to file_result.txt.

```
(while read ADDR; do grep "${ADDR}" file2.txt >> file_result.txt ) < file1.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

quite like manipulating text using SQL:

```
$ cat file1
b@address.com
a@address.com
c@address.com
d@address.com
$ cat file2
10712 e@address.com
11457 b@address.com
19985 f@address.com
22519 d@address.com
$ join -1 1 -2 2 <(sort file1) <(sort -k2 file2) | awk '{print $2,$1}'
11457 b@address.com
22519 d@address.com
```

- make keys sorted(we use `emails` as keys here)
- join on keys(`file1.column1`, `file2.column2`)
- format output(use `awk` to reverse columns)

Answer (score 2):

As you've learned about `diff` and `comm`, now it's time to learn about another tool in the unix toolbox, `join`.

Join does just what the name indicates, it joins together 2 files. The way you join is based on keys embedded in the file.

The number 1 restraint on using join is that the data must be sorted in both files on the same column.

```
file1
a abc
b bcd
c cde

file2
a rec1
b rec2
c rec3


join file1 file2
a abc rec1
b bcd rec2
c cde rec3
```

you can consult the join man page for how to reduce and reorder the columns of output. for example

```
1>join -o 1.1 2.2 file1 file2
a rec1
b rec2
c rec3
```

You can use your code for file name input to turn this into a generalizable script.

Your solution using a pipeline inside a for loop will work for small sets of data, but as the size of data grows, the cost of starting a new process for each word you are searching for will drag down the run time.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` one-liner can help you do that -

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}($2 in a){print $0 > "f3.txt"}' f1.txt f2.txt
```

`NR` and `FNR` are `awk's` built-in variables that stores the line numbers. `NR` does not get reset to 0 when working with two files. `FNR` does. So while that condition is true we add everything to an array `a`. Once the `first file` is completed, we check for the `second column` of `second file`. If a match is present in the `array` we put the entire line in a file `f3.txt`. If not then we ignore it.

#### Using data from Kev's solution:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat f1.txt 
b@address.com
a@address.com
c@address.com
d@address.com
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat f2.txt 
10712 e@address.com
11457 b@address.com
19985 f@address.com
22519 d@address.com
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}($2 in a){print $0 > "f3.txt"}' f1.txt f2.txt 
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat f3.txt 
11457 b@address.com
22519 d@address.com
```